# NVARCHAR Dropping Decimal Points in Email Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, casting

I'm busy modifying a script which outputs data from a temp table to a script sent to our users. It's monitoring our SQL usage statistics and used for reporting and so forth. I've output the temp table prior to the email code below and it's maintaining my decimal column correctly as "12, 12345" or `DECIMAL(18, 5)`.

However the final section that sends the email (attached below) keeps on dropping my decimal points and will output as "12, 000" instead. Does anyone perhaps have some assistance please, I've tried various castings within the script, replacing "," with "." and visa-versa.

```
SET @xml = CAST((SELECT  
                     LEFT(UPPER([Server]), 20) AS 'td', '',
                     LEFT([Database], 30) AS 'td', '',
                     LEFT(Device, 30) AS 'td', '',
                     LEFT([GB_Growth], 20) AS 'td', '',
                     REPLACE(CAST([GB_Current] AS DECIMAL(18, 5)), '.', ',') AS 'td', '',
                     REPLACE(CAST([GB_Previous] AS DECIMAL(18, 5)), '.', ',')        AS 'td', '',
                     ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(20),[Current_Date], 20), '--------------') AS 'td', '',
                     ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(20),[Previous_Date], 20), '--------------') AS 'td', ''
                 FROM    
                     [tempdb].[dbo].[DB_Dev_Sizediff] 
                 ORDER BY  
                     [Server], [Database]
                 FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

I've left my attempt in the above script (which doesn't work) but I'm looking to get this working for the following columns:

```
GB_Growth, GB_Current and GB_Previous
```

The original function in the script was doing the following however I've been playing around to attempt various different things, hence why the above is different:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(23), [GB_Current]), '-----') AS 'td', ''
```

Again everything leading up to this point is in DECIMAL and I have confirmed this right up until this step.

Screenshot of output

[image]

Full Script:

```
--Temp Table
IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.DB_Dev_Sizediff', N'U') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE [tempdb].[dbo].[DB_Dev_Sizediff] (
      [Server]        [sysname]
    , [Database]      [sysname]
    , [Device]        [sysname]
    , [GB_Current]    [decimal](18,5)
    , [GB_Previous]   [decimal](18,5)
    , [GB_Growth]     [decimal](18,5)
    , [Current_Date]  [datetime]
    , [Previous_Date] [datetime]  
  )
ELSE TRUNCATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.DB_Dev_Sizediff ; 

-- Temp Table 2
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.dbspace', N'U') IS NULL
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbspace] (
      [runid]      [int]
    , [date]       [smalldatetime]
    , [servername] [sysname]
    , [dbname]     [varchar](128)
    , [devname]    [sysname]
    , [type]       [char](10)
    , [gb_alloc]   [decimal](18,5)
    , [gb_used]    [decimal](18,5)
  ) ; 


-- Get Latest Run From Run ID
WITH Current_Run AS
(
  SELECT   d.runid
         , d.servername
         , d.dbname
         , d.devname
         , d.gb_alloc
         , d.gb_used
         , d.[date]
  FROM   dbo.dbspace d
  WHERE  d.runid = (SELECT MAX(runid) FROM   dbo.dbspace)
) ,

Previous_Run AS
(
  SELECT   d.runid
         , d.servername
         , d.dbname
         , d.devname
         , d.gb_alloc
         , d.gb_used
         , d.[date]
  FROM   dbo.dbspace d
  WHERE  d.runid = (SELECT MAX(runid) FROM   dbo.dbspace WHERE  runid < (SELECT MAX(runid) FROM dbo.dbspace))  
)

INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.DB_Dev_Sizediff
SELECT  CASE WHEN cr.servername IS NOT NULL 
             THEN cr.servername 
             ELSE pr.servername 
         END AS 'Server'
      , CASE WHEN cr.dbname IS NOT NULL 
             THEN cr.dbname 
             ELSE pr.dbname 
         END AS 'Database'
      , CASE WHEN cr.devname IS NOT NULL 
             THEN cr.devname 
             ELSE pr.devname 
         END AS 'Device'
      , CAST(cr.gb_alloc as DECIMAL (18, 5))
      , CAST(pr.gb_alloc as DECIMAL (18, 5))
      , CASE WHEN cr.gb_alloc IS NOT NULL
             THEN cr.gb_alloc - ISNULL(pr.gb_alloc,0) 
             ELSE 0 - pr.gb_alloc 
        END  AS 'GB_Growth'
      , cr.[date]
      , pr.[date]
FROM    Current_Run cr
FULL OUTER JOIN Previous_Run pr
ON      cr.servername = pr.servername
AND     cr.dbname = pr.dbname
AND     cr.devname = pr.devname
WHERE   cr.gb_alloc = pr.gb_alloc 
OR      cr.gb_alloc IS NULL
OR      pr.gb_alloc IS NULL   

--If any changes, compile our email below
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tempdb.dbo.DB_Dev_Sizediff)
BEGIN
  DECLARE   @subj   VARCHAR(200)
          , @body  NVARCHAR(MAX)
          , @xml   NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT    @subj  = 'Database device size changes'
  SET       @body = '<html><body>
               <p><font size="2" face="monaco">                         
               Listed below are are all databases that have grown since our last scan. <BR><BR> 
               <H3>Database Device Size Changes in GB</H3>
               <table border="1" cellpadding="5"> 
               <p><font size="2" face="monaco">                  
               <tr>
               <th>Server</th> <th>Database</th> <th>Device</th> <th>GB Growth</th> <th>GB Current</th> <th>GB Previous</th> <th>Current Check</th> <th>Previous Check</th></tr>'
  SET   @xml =  CAST(
                (SELECT  LEFT(UPPER([Server]),20)                                      AS 'td',''
                       , LEFT([Database], 30)                                          AS 'td',''
                       , LEFT(Device, 30)                                              AS 'td',''
                       , [GB_Growth]                                           AS 'td',''
                       , [GB_Current]               AS 'td',''
                       , [GB_Previous]        AS 'td',''
                       , ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(20),[Current_Date],20),'--------------')  AS 'td',''
                       , ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(20),[Previous_Date],20),'--------------') AS 'td',''
                 FROM    [tempdb].[dbo].[DB_Dev_Sizediff] 
                 ORDER BY  [Server], [Database]
                 FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) 
                 AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

--Compile Email and Send It using Defined Settings           
  SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
       @profile_name =  @profile_name
     , @recipients   =  @recipients
     , @subject      =  @subj  
     , @body         =  @body
     , @body_format  = 'HTML'
END
```

Source - http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Monitoring/118079/

Comment: I can't reproduce your truncation, it displays correctly for me. Make sure your `GB_Current` column has the correct value and data type. It shouldn't be necessary to convert it to decimal if it's already decimal.

Comment: Thanks @EzLo, I have ensured that its correct, this is how its declared when creating the temp table above this function:  " [GB_Current]    [decimal](18,5)". Ill attempt again by removing other cast functions around it.

Comment: You state "keeps on dropping my decimal points and will output as "12, 000" instead". Your code uses `REPLACE` to do that.

Comment: It keeps on dropping any value/digits after the decimal points, the separator isnt the issue as I was just trying various techniques. Apologies should have stated that better on my side. Iv edited the OP and added the full script into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what was happening in the background however I decided to modify the script to never use a temp table and save straight into a physical table. Once doing that I modified the from clause in my final XML building statement and the query worked without applying any logic to the actual column.

Thanks for the help and suggestions, guess I just needed to stop looking at it for a bit to ease the mind.